# Get error values of fields

Tags: redux-form

I wanted to get the error values for the `name`s of all the fields in my form. I wanted to show a "form-level" error saying "you need to go look at this field" and clicking individual messages will scroll them to that field.

I haven't been able to figure out how to get anything other then the "form-level" error from `this.props.error`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar requirement and I used `getFormSyncErrors` selector which returns an object whose keys are the name of the invalid fields and whose values are the corresponding error:

```
{
  recipientAddress: "Required", 
  recipientCity: "Required", 
  recipientZip: "Required"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is this documented? I can't find it. I thought it was very bad to use selectors because in the docs I read "This decorator causes the component to render() every time one of the selected values changes.". Also may you lease show an example of how to use?

Comment: Documentation is here http://redux-form.com/7.0.3/docs/api/Selectors.md/ and there's also a basic example. I can't read anything about performance issue on the doc..

Comment: Oh! Thanks Dario, the perf warning is for `formValues` apparently - http://redux-form.com/7.0.3/docs/api/FormValues.md/ - I don't understand why that is. I hope these selectors like `getFormSyncErrors` doesn't have that perf issue, do you think it would?